# Blackberry (Java) - Setting scrolling be not focused on objects on the screen

Tags: java, blackberry

I have a mainscreen which currently scrolls (and I have the arrows on the right) but the scrolling seems to be focused on the ButtonField objects that I have on the page. Is there any way to set the scrolling to be non-focused scrolling (moving a few pixels each time). Is there a way to set this?

Other ideas I have had (which sound hacky so I want to avoid):
- Placing NullFields around to scroll
- Manually listening to the  trackwheelRoll event and moving appropriately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not really how scrolling works on trackball BlackBerry devices.  It's always based on the change of focus from one field to another.  The only time the whole screen may scroll "smoothly" is when there are no fields that accept focus (or on touchscreen devices such as the Storm).

To use an analogy: just think of each focusable field on the screen as being like a line of text in a text editor.  Just by moving the cursor with the arrow keys, you can get the screen to scroll but only when the cursor hits the edge of the current visible screen, and then only to the next line in a one-line increment.  On trackball BlackBerrys, the trackball is the equivalent of the arrow keys -- and unfortunately there isn't an analog to "smoothly dragging the scrollbar with a mouse" in the text editor.  Hope this makes sense!

Comment: Thanks for the information. The issue is that I have text that is likely to fill more than one screen which would mean that without one-line scrolls it may not be possible to see the entire text.